# "I was almost there" in French?

Tags: pronoms, ordre-des-mots, adverbes, indications-de-lieu

I was wondering how you would say 'I was almost there' in French. I tried a couple of things but it looked a bit weird..

> J'étais là presque.

Or a different order?

> Je presque étais là.

Or should I use '*y*' instead of '*là*'?

> J'y étais presque.

Or maybe this?

> J'y presque étais.

Or something completely different. I don't know... :/

Comment: Just as a note of interest: "_là_" takes an accent when meaning "there".

Comment: tip: almost nothing can interrupt the flow between a subject pronoun and a verb: you can never put something like presque there, but only y, en, object pronouns, ne, and I think that's it. (plus the weird, legalistic je soussigné(e)). it helps you remember this if you think of "subject pronoun + (ne) + (y/en/object pronoun) + verb" as one big word that you happen to put some extra spaces in when you write.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The best way to say it would be :

> J'y étais presque.

Comment: without the accent please.:-)

Comment: The best, and the only one among candidates... Note that other sentences are wrong, except "J'étais presque là", but it wasn't a candidate :)

Comment: Sure not at prèsque ;-)  (it has been edited meanwhile)